# Invalid Identifier with NSRect frame = [self frame]

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently trying to figure out how to alter frames from a webcam for a motion detection game. I am very new to Objective-C, and I have been unable to find a simple way to do this.

My question here is about an error message related to this method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(QTCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
  didOutputVideoFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)videoFrame
     withSampleBuffer:(QTSampleBuffer *)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(QTCaptureConnection *)connection
{


    CIContext *myCIContext;
    const NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attr[] = {
        NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
        NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
        NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 32,
        0
    };
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pf = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:(void *)&attr];
    myCIContext = [CIContext contextWithCGLContext: CGLGetCurrentContext()
                                       pixelFormat: [pf CGLPixelFormatObj]
                                           options: nil];
    CVImageBufferRef releasedImageBuffer;
    CVBufferRetain(videoFrame);

    CIImage *picture = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:releasedImageBuffer];
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    CGRect imageRect;
    imageRect = [picture extent];

    [colorCorrectionFilter setValue:picture forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [effectFilter setValue:[colorCorrectionFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];

    // render our resulting image into our context
    [ciContext drawImage:[compositeFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"] 
                 atPoint:CGPointMake((int)((frame.size.width - imageRect.size.width) * 0.5), (int)((frame.size.height - imageRect.size.height) * 0.5)) // use integer coordinates to avoid interpolation
                fromRect:imageRect];

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        //basically, have frame to be released refer to the current frame
        //then update the reference to the current frame with the next frame in the "video stream"
        releasedImageBuffer = mCurrentImageBuffer;
        mCurrentImageBuffer = videoFrame;
    }

    CVBufferRelease(releasedImageBuffer);

}
```

The error message produced says:

```
warning: 'MyRecorderController' may not respond to '-frame'
error: invalid initializer
```

and the line highlighted is

```
NSRect frame = [self frame];
```

My header is currently like so:

```
#import <QuickTime/ImageCompression.h>
#import <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>


@interface MyRecorderController : NSObject{ 
    IBOutlet QTCaptureView *mCaptureView;

    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *videoDevicePopUp;
    NSMutableDictionary *namesToDevicesDictionary;
    NSString *defaultDeviceMenuTitle;

    CVImageBufferRef mCurrentImageBuffer;
    QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput *mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput;

    // filters for CI rendering
    CIFilter            *colorCorrectionFilter; // hue saturation brightness control through one CI filter
    CIFilter            *effectFilter;          // zoom blur filter
    CIFilter            *compositeFilter;       // composites the timecode over the video
    CIContext           *ciContext;

    QTCaptureSession *mCaptureSession;
    QTCaptureMovieFileOutput *mCaptureMovieFileOutput;
    QTCaptureDeviceInput *mCaptureDeviceInput;

}

@end
```

I have looked at tutorial code, and I do not understand what I have done wrong. As far as I can see (judging by said various sample code) I should not need to include a protocol in this - which is what other websites have suggested.
I have tried it though, and while it does compile it ends up outputting:

```
2011-01-18 10:19:11.511 MyRecorder[9972:c903] -[MyRecorderController frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001525f0
2011-01-18 10:19:11.512 MyRecorder[9972:c903] *** Ignoring exception: -[MyRecorderController frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001525f0
```

Is there anything I have done wrong which has caused this? If not, is there a better way to be able to manipulate frames from a webcam (and output them to the screen)?

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a method frame on MyRecorderController - which just doesn't have that method. Maybe that class should inherit from `UIView`, or you need to implement that method.

Ask yourself what frame you mean, and write the appropriate method.

Comment: I believe that it should be the NSView's method for 'frame' that it is meant to inherit from - which should be there since the header inherits from NSObject. When I click on the 'frame' method on X-Code, it comes up with a lot of classes, NSView being one of them.
Is the problem here that I have not defined *which* frame method I want to implement?

Comment: But MyRecorderController doesn't descend from NSView, so why would it have NSView's methods?

Comment: When saying "NSRect frame = [self frame];" which frame do you mean? If you know the answer, you have the fix. :-)